# Comcast gateway parental setting block CIDR IP Range

Tags: routing, ip-address, blocking

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I am having trouble adding CIDR IP ranges e.g. `206.111.0.0/16` to my [Comcast Gateway](http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/about-wireless-gateway). I went to `Manage Sites` and it says:

```
Please Input a valid URL format or an IPv4 address in the format #.#.#.#
```

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Based on that error message, I guess, that device does not support ip-range bans.

Comment: That sucks, the firewall does not have an advanced settings... only parental website blocking.